# vb.net - imagen no se muestra a la hora de ejecutar WPF

Tags: vb.net, wpf

Buenas, Tengo la siguiente diseño:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="CadetBlue">
    <Border BorderBrush="DimGray " BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" Background="AliceBlue" Padding="5" CornerRadius="28" Margin="52,0,155,219" Height="52" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="46" LastChildFill="True" Margin="-2,-1,0,-7" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="275">
            <Image x:Name="image" Height="46" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="41" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/user (1).png" />
            <TextBox BorderBrush="Transparent" x:Name="textBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="234" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero tengo problema a la hora de ejecutar, porque ignora la imagen y solo se muestra esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Añado, que a la hora de agregar la imagen lo hice como un recurso. A que se debe el problema? Como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Me suena a que el espacio en el nombre de tu imagen te está jugando una mala pasada

Answer (score 0):

Casi con total seguridad no existe el archivo "pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/user (1).png". Cuando usas siteoforigin en lugar de application, tienes que copiar el archivo a la ruta que indicas (respecto al ejecutable).

Comprueba que existe el archivo, que de verdad se llama user (1).png (con espacio en medio), y prueba con application en lugar de siteoforigin, ya que dices que lo has agregado como recurso.

Creo que esta información te vendrá bien: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx#The_siteoforigin_____Authority

Answer (score 0):

Prueba poniéndole sólo esta dirección:

```
 Source="Resources/user(1).png"
```

Me ha ocurrido que al darle F5 no me cargan las imagénes.
Sin embargo con Ctrl + F5 todo corre OK